# Huffman tree wrong output

Tags: java

this is my first time using stackoverflow to ask a question and i hope you guys can help me out :)

i am working on a projecting to implement Huffman code. The problem is that i got a wrong result when i try to print the code.

Here is the input file and correct result:

```
Symbol    A     B   C   D    _
frequency 0.35 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.15
Code      11   100 00  01  101
```

the result i got:

```
Symbol    A     B   C   D    _
frequency 0.35 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.15
Code      00   011  10  11  010
```

Here is the class file:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
Node left;
        Node right;
    Node parent;
    String text;
    Float frequency;

    public Node(String textIn, Float frequencies) {
        text = textIn;
        frequency = frequencies;
    }

    public Node(Float d) {
        text = "";
        frequency = d;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node n) {
        if (frequency < n.frequency) {
            return -1;
        } else if (frequency > n.frequency) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void buildPath(Node root,String code)
{
    if (root!=null)
    {   
        if (root.left!=null)
            buildPath(root.left, code+"0");
        if (root.right!=null)   
          buildPath(root.right,code+"1");
        if (root.left==null && root.right==null)
            System.out.println(root.text+": "+code);               
    }       
}



    public static Node makeHuffmanTree(Float[] frequencies, String text[]) {
        PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            Node n = new Node(text[i], frequencies[i]);
            queue.add(n);
        }
        Node root = null;
        while (queue.size() > 1) {
            Node least1 = queue.poll();
            Node least2 = queue.poll();
            Node combined = new Node(least1.frequency + least2.frequency);
            combined.right = least1;
            combined.left = least2;
            least1.parent = combined;
            least2.parent = combined;
            queue.add(combined);
            // Keep track until we actually find the root
            root = combined;
        }
        return root;
    }
```

I think there is something wrong with my printing method?

and heres my main

```
public static void main(String[] args)
String[] Symbol = {"A","B","C","D","_"};
Float[] frequency = (0.35,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.15};

        Node root = Node.makeHuffmanTree(frequency, Symbol);
        Node.buildPath(root, "");
```

Comment: For your printing method, what exactly do you expect your printing method to do? Print them in prefix order, in-order, or what?

Comment: I don't understand what your `printFromPreOrder` method is doing. If you're trying to print code, shouldn't you be trying to find the path from the root to each leaf node? I don't think this has anything to with the text you've stored at the node.

Comment: mmm How do i  find the path to each node? i know i have to print a 0 when i take the left branch and print a 1 when i take a right branch.

Comment: Before we answer that though; what exactly do you want your printing method to do?

Comment: I basically want the printing method traverse the tree to a value i want, printing out 0 when i take the left branch and print out 1 when i take the right path.

Comment: Then figure out how to get to that value first. Once you get that part, *then* you can add in how to print out its Huffman code.

Comment: Could you provide your main, too.

Comment: Have you tried walking through the code in an IDE debugger?  If not, that's the place to start.

Comment: Guys thanks for your help, now i am able to build a path. But the problem is my result is still wrong, but really close. So i am thinking there is some little mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your output, the lengths of the individual codes look fine, so I'm less convinced it's a tree traversal issue now.

The discrepancy could very well be in how you're building the tree. When you pop off two elements from your queue and make a new tree with those two as subtrees, the choice of which subtree is the "left" subtree affects the resulting codes.

Looking at your while loop, I see

```
while (queue.size() > 1) {
        Node least1 = queue.poll();
        Node least2 = queue.poll();
        Node combined = new Node(least1.frequency + least2.frequency);
        combined.right = least1;
        combined.left = least2;
        least1.parent = combined;
        least2.parent = combined;
        queue.add(combined);
        // Keep track until we actually find the root
        root = combined;
}
```

<del>I haven't worked through the example fully, but</del> Having worked through your example, I think just changing to `combined.left = least1` and `combined.right = least2` instead of the other way around will give the codes you're expecting.

Comment: i changed the code to what you suggested and the result is still a little off. Now i get D : 00, C : 01, B : 100, _ : 101 and A : 11

Comment: That's because `C` and `D` have the same frequency; your queue could pop them in either order (it looks like you're popping `D` first, but the "correct" result pops `C` first). If you change your `compareTo` to break ties in frequency, that should do the trick.